# Puppeteer/chromium doesn't go to the next route on click. Why is it staying on the same route and trying to open the view on the current url?

Tags: angularjs, puppeteer

By clicking on the button element with ng-click (which has `$state.go` in the `ng-click` function) puppeteer/chromium doesn't go to the next route. Why is it staying on the same route and trying to open the view on the current url? 
Everything works on the real site when I click on my own (without puppeteer).

I'm getting the Errors:

> StackTrace is not defined and $digest already in progress

I tried:

```
const startBtn = ".button-selector";

await page.waitFor(startBtn);
await page.click(startBtn);
await page.waitForNavigation();
await page.waitForSelector(".new-selector");
```

Comment: The `await` operator uses ES6 promises which are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg is there some workaround for this problem? Await works fine for page.waitForSelector on other examples where I don't have redirect. Thanks

Comment: Read [AngularJS Error Reference - Diagnosing Action Already In Progress Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#diagnosing-this-error).

Comment: Also [AngularJS Error Reference - inprog - Inconsistent API (Sync/Async)](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#inconsistent-api-sync-async-).

Answer (score 0):

The `await` operator uses ES6 promises which are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Convert the promises to AngularJS promises with `$q.when` and avoid the `await` operator:

```
const startBtn = ".button-selector";

var p1 = $q.when(page.waitFor(startBtn));
var p2 = p1.then(function() {
   return $q.when(page.click(startBtn));
});
var p3 = p2.then(function() {
   return $q.when(page.waitForNavigation());
});
var p4 = p3.then(function() {
   return $q.when(page.waitForSelector(".new-selector"));
});

return p4;
```

The [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) method wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a [$q promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api). This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

The `.then` method of an AngularJS promise is integrated with AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: I don't use puppeteer inside the AngularJs app...Puppeteer tests are separated from AngularJS app as different repo, so $q service isn't the part of the tests. Is it possible to work together (AngularJS app and Puppeteer), but separated?  I'm running puppeteer directly on staging env and getting these errors. Thanks